# Access Data from windows server to linux Server

Tags: windows, linux

I want to know how to transfer data from windows server to linux server.

I had written one utility in c++ which sends data from windows machine to linux machine using sockets.but its using more bandwidth because of this my website is going down.
and if i copy manually also its taking more bandwidth.

I don't want to happens this.

Is there any other way which transfer data from one server to another with less bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Compress it.  You can always use something like `rsync` or simple `scp`.  Both support compression.  Outside of that, if you have 10 gigabytes of data, you're going to use 10 gigabytes of bandwidth.